# Increment or Decrement text box value(not attribute) within a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

There are input tags in a loop for 39 times like below

```
for (i = 0; i <= 39; i++) {
document.write("<button id='minus'>-</button><input type='text' id='input' value='0' ng-model='number" + i + "'><button id='plus'>+</button><br><br>");
};

let pb = document.getElementById("plus");
let mb = document.getElementById("minus");
let text = document.getElementById("input");

pb.onclick = function() {
let x = text.getAttribute("value");
text.setAttribute("value", ++x);
};

mb.onclick = function() {
let x = text.getAttribute("value");
if (x >= 1) {
text.setAttribute("value", --x);
};
};
```

but the thing I need is to increment/decrement textbox value with that specific ng-model number when I click the buttons beside in a loop.

And also those text boxes giving information to "Total" textbox above where it displays addition of all the values in the text boxes. so just updating value attribute not working, a bit angular involved, so please help me to solve this problem.

([dev.pfokus.com/product/caponi](http://dev.pfokus.com/product/caponi/)) open this url and select product, quantity and it will take you to colors selection, observe the console how its behaving. write some number in the color box and total field gets updated. please do check the console and help me in how to solve the issue of adding +/- buttons.

([justpaste.it/5tbwj](https://justpaste.it/5tbwj/)) this is the code in directives of angular js in my webiste directory. this is what taking input values from the text box, please try to trigger this with +/- buttons.

These are images of console when I added "1" to a textbox and when I added "2" to the same textbox through keyboard input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbVR7.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ALTM.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You get 39 buttons all with the same id, make them unique. You can use the data attribute to set the ng-modal. When you receive a click event, read the data attribute

Comment: @Grumpy (http://dev.pfokus.com/product/caponi) open this url and select product, quantity and it will take you to colors selection, observe the console how its behaving. write some number in the color box and total field gets updated. please do check the console and help me in how to solve the issue of adding +/- buttons, thanks.

Comment: You need to start by fixing your duplicate IDs, you can’t expect this to work properly otherwise. `getElementById` will only ever get you the first element in the document with the specified ID, if you illegally use the same IDs more than one, you will not be able to find them using this method.

Comment: @04FS I can differentiate by focussing the nearby text field or classes to them. but the thing i need is sending the present text field value to total. if I'm typing in it, it's working, if incrementing the value with button, it's not sending the data to the total value. AngularJS involved, so need help with that.

Comment: There is probably some change event handler attached somewhere - but the change event only fires when the field value gets changed by the user, not when it happens via script. You can probably get this to work by explicitly triggering a change event on the field, after you changed its value via your click buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709149/10955263 explains the basic principle.

Comment: Is there any reason this question is tagged with PHP or AngularJS, while there are no such code parts involved?

Comment: @NicoHaase Yes there is a reason, This is just an example code that I gave, If some one answered, I'll take the logic and apply on my side. My side is on php and angularjs. that's why I tagged them. provided a link. that webpage is single page application through angularjs and renders php.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dLuzemrx/

I am also new to Angular JS, did just the working required in question. Any optimisation or corrections, please feel free to do it.

JS Code:

```
var dataHTML = "";
for (i = 0; i <= 39; i++) {
    dataHTML += '<button ng-click="value_'+ i +' = value_'+ i +' - 1">-</button><input ng-value="value_'+ i +'"><button ng-click="value_'+ i +' = value_'+ i +' + 1">+</button><br><br>';
}
document.querySelector('[ng-app="myApp"]').innerHTML = dataHTML;
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "Hello World!";
    for (i = 0; i <= 39; i++) {
        $scope['value_'+ i] = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: (https://justpaste.it/5tbwj) this is the code in directives of angular js in my webiste directory. this is what taking input values from the text box, please try to trigger this with +/- buttons, thank you.

Comment: I had just a given a way like, how you can try on your own. As I already stated in my answer that, I am too a newbie in Angular. I won't be able to help you the way you requested here. If my answer gives you some idea then it's good else wait till others gives you a suitable solution.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen yours, I appreciate your work and kind reply, Thank you :)

Comment: If answer found useful, you can accept it or just up-vote it. :)